# Connecting external hard disk drive into a Linux vps

Tags: linux, vps

Is it possible to connect an external hard disk drive into a vps folder, say /drive using linux centos 6-64 vps? How can we do this? Thanks

Comment: Technically: Yes. Almost all of it depends on your virtualisation software though, and you did not mention that.

Comment: Hi, I am new to using vps, i would like the wget to save result directly in my external hard disk drive instead of in the vps, how can I do? The only thing i know is that the vps is formatted in centos 6-64, nothing else is saved there yet. tks

Comment: Did you setup that VPS yourself or are you using some kind of third party service that provides VPSs?

Comment: Is a vps from a third party and its formatted centos 6-64

Comment: Yes thats it...